# Show error correction ability of a code

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u ∈ F_2^n. A binary code C of length n is said to correct the error
pattern u if and only if, for all c,c'∈ C with c \ne c', we have d(c, c+u) <
d(c', c+u). Assume that u1, u2 ∈ F_2^n agree in at least the positions where
1 occurs in u1. Suppose that C corrects the error pattern u2. Prove that
C also corrects the error pattern u1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.